# How to get table names from external DB in non public schema

Tags: database, 9

I am writing a configuration entity modul in drupal 9. I want to list all tables, from an external database (postgis) in the schema called gi. The switch between the databases is no problem. I'm searching for a way, to only get the name of the table called gruenzuege to put this in a markup form.

//the form where to save the table

```
 $form['tables'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('Tables'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE, // Added
      '#collapsed' => FALSE,  // Added
  ];
```

//External Database connection

```
$postgis_database = array(
      'database' => $drugis_postgis_connection->getdatabase(),
      'username' => $drugis_postgis_connection->getusername(),
      'password' => $drugis_postgis_connection->getpassword(),
      'host' => $drugis_postgis_connection->gethost(),
      'driver' => 'pgsql'
  );
Database::addConnectionInfo('postgis', 'default', $postgis_database);
Database::setActiveConnection('default', 'postgis');
```

//example for fetching table:gruenzuege in drupal

```
    $results = Database::getConnection('default', 'postgis')->query('SELECT * FROM "gi"."gruenzuege"')->fetchAll();
dpm($results);
```

I don't understand how to query to another schema, to get only, the table names of the schema gi? It is actually the only table. Thanks for help

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) This sounds like a question about SQL rather than Drupal - if not please could you edit and make clear what the Drupal part of it is? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, i hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

listing all table names in an array

```
$example_database = array(
      'database' => ...,
      'username' => ...,
      'password' => ...,
      'host' => ...,
      'driver' => 'pgsql'
  );

Database::addConnectionInfo('example_key', 'default', $example_database);
Database::setActiveConnection('default', 'example_key');

$result=Database::getConnection('default', 'example_key')->query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '" . example_schema . "';");
  $tables = $result->fetchAll();

foreach( $tables as $table ) {
      dpm($table->table_name);
      $tableNames[] = $table->table_name;
  }

Database::setActiveConnection();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).